# Regular expression to ensure string does NOT exactly match

Tags: regex, string, match

I want to build a regular expression where it should only match if the string is NOT exactly "amp".

What I want is:

This string should NOT match:
"venues-in/united-states/new-york/amp"

These strings should match:
"venues-in/united-states/new-york/amphi"
"venues-in/united-states/new-york/camping"

My current regex is: 
`venues-in\/([a-zA-Z0-9-+'.]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9-+'.]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9-+'.]+)`

I tried playing with the `!` operator on https://regex101.com/, and negative lookahead:
`^(?=amp)([a-zA-Z0-9-+'.]+)`

But I can't figure it out. Please help.

Comment: Which language/engine? Negative lookahead would be nice here, but isn't always supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
venues-in\/([a-zA-Z0-9-+'.]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9-+'.]+)\/(?!amp$)([a-zA-Z0-9-+'.]+)
```

The negative lookahead syntax is `(?!pattern)`. The `$` is used to make sure that the word checked against is exactly `amp` with no suffix.

If your string could be something like `venues-in/united-states/new-york/amp/whatever` too, adjust the lookahead to `(?!amp(?:$|\/)`.

Comment: Escape the dash `-` in the character class.

Comment: @Toto not necessarily, most regex engines can handle a dash after a range just fine. It doesn't hurt though.

Comment: Sure, but it seems cleaner for me.Nevertheless upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work,

```
venues-in\/([a-zA-Z0-9\-+'.]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9\-+'.]+)\/(?!amp$)([a-zA-Z0-9\-+'.]+)
```

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/prRSnE/1)

Comment: Escape the dash `-` in the character class.

Answer (score 0):

Why not match for `\bamp\b` and then in your program do a not equal. In Perl that would be

```
if ($string !~ /\bamp\b/) {
    # Do stuff with out amp
}
else {
    # Do stuff with amp
}
```